# How to check if a string changes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am quite new in iOS programming but I need it to test out a prototype.
I am receiving a value over bluetooth, which changes when a button is pressed on the physical prototype.

In my app a action has to follow when the button is pressed, therefore I need to know when the value has changed.

I have tried everything I could think of and looked everywhere but found no solution.
This is my current code:

```
-(void)bean:(PTDBean *)bean didUpdateScratchNumber:(NSNumber *)number withValue:(NSData *)data{
int value = *(int*)([data bytes]);
NSString *lastvalue = nil;
NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
    NSLog(@"ScratchWaarde: %d", value);
if ([newValue isEqualToString:lastvalue]) {
    NSLog(@"Last Value: %@", lastvalue);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Pushed");
        lastvalue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Are you also new in programming generally? If so, you might be a lot happier learning Swift instead of trying to do this in Objective-C. It seems probably that Objective-C is confusing you.

Comment: what does it make you to think if the `lastValue` is a _local_ variable then it keeps its value _globally_? you look new to every type of programming, not only to iOS, huhh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it looks like the OP expects lastValue to be kept as state on the object, so...

```
// in this class's interface
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *lastValue;

-(void)bean:(PTDBean *)bean didUpdateScratchNumber:(NSNumber *)number withValue:(NSData *)data{

    // it looks like the OP is trying to get a string from the data, so...
    NSString *newValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"ScratchWaarde: %d", value);
    if ([newValue isEqualToString:self.lastvalue]) {
        NSLog(@"Last Value: %@", self.lastvalue);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Pushed");
        self.lastvalue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code makes no sense. You are saying:

```
NSString *lastvalue = nil;
NSString *newValue = // ...
if ([newValue isEqualToString:lastvalue]) {
```

Under no circumstances will `newValue` *ever* be equal to `lastValue`, because `lastValue` is guaranteed to be nil, because that is the value you are setting it to in the first line (and `newValue`, because you are setting it to an actual NSString, is guaranteed *not* to be nil).

So, while I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, this obviously isn't it. It's not so much a programming matter as a matter of simple logical thought. The program can only do what you tell it to do, and what you are telling it to do is silly.

(In all probability what you are not grasping is that `lastvalue` is purely local to this method, so it is new every time your method is called. If you want a *persistent* `lastvalue`, you need a property global to the class, not a local variable.)

Comment: I was aware that the code I posted did not make sense, I only have some experience in Processing before starting with Objective-C, so I just tried to figure out how to get it to work with the limited knowledge that I had. I knew that a local variable wouldn't work, I did not however about creating a property global to the class, which sounds helpful, I will look into that!